# how to fix google+ login connection in android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, google-api, google-plus

Hi I'm android beginner

My code had worked a few days ago , suddenly there was problem

How did these errors come from?

**Error log**

```
05-18 11:01:52.756 710-722/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
                                          java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
                                              at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:15401)
                                              at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2512)
                                              at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:685)
                                              at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:325)
                                              at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:275)
                                              at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

....

```
05-18 11:01:52.796 748-748/com.buttering.roler E/Login_Activity: Connection to Play Services Failed, error: 4, reason: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{426e34f0: android.os.BinderProxy@423cbdb8}, message=null}
05-18 11:01:52.796 710-1728/? E/Parcel: Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope
                                    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope
                                        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it clearly say

```
Connection to Play Services Failed, error: 4, reason: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED
```

SIGNIN_REQUIRED

`public static final int SIGN_IN_REQUIRED`

> The client attempted to connect to the service but the user is not
>   signed in. The client may choose to continue without using the API.
>   Alternately, if hasResolution() returns true the client may call
>   startResolutionForResult(Activity, int) to prompt the user to sign in.
>   After the sign in activity returns with RESULT_OK further attempts
>   should succeed.
>
> Constant Value: 4